# How does one arrive at "fair" priors for spatial and non-spatial effects

Tags: probability, spatial, bayesian, stan, hierarchical-bayesian

In a basic BYM model may be written as

[image] 
sometimes with covariates but that doesn't matter much here. Where *s* are the spatially structured effects and *u* the unstructured effects over units.

In Congdon (2020) they refer to the fair prior on these as one in which
[image]
where [image] is the average number of neighbors in the adjacency matrix.
It is defined similarly (in terms of precision, I think) in Bernardinelli et al. (1995).

However, for the gamma distribution, scaling appears to [only impact the scale term](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1009938/probability-density-function-of-scaled-gamma-random-variable)

I haven't been able to find a worked example for this, and don't understand how the priors are arrived at, for example, in the [well-known lip cancer data](https://mc-stan.org/users/documentation/case-studies/icar_stan.html)

I am hoping someone could help me understand how these are reached in this setting, even in the simple case of two gamma hyperpriors.

References
Congdon, P. D. (2019). Bayesian Hierarchical Models: With Applications Using R, Second Edition (2nd edition). Chapman and Hall/CRC.

Bernardinelli, L., Clayton, D. and Montomoli, C. (1995). Bayesian estimates of disease maps: How important are priors? Statistics in Medicine 14 2411–2431.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.

Comment: Great question, however, it belongs on stats.stackexchange.com. I've flagged it for migration.

Comment: ah, ok, thank you!